# How to get all unique permutations of a binary matrix and their ranks in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a loop that would get all unique matrices. The only parameters would be a range from 0:1 and the matrix having a dimension of 4x4. This would mean that there would be 65,536 unique matrices (2^16). I define unique as no two matrices share the same elements in the same coordinates. Here is what I have so far:

```
binary <- function(m, n)
matrix(sample(0:1, m * n, replace = TRUE), m, n)
```

where m = 4 and n = 4.

Not sure how to generate a loop that would calculate all unique permutations.

Comment: how do you define a unique matrix?

Comment: All elements should be different different?

Comment: Each matrix should not be the same. I define "the same" as no two matrices sharing the same elements in the same coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

A very fast solution using `RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral`.

```
binary2 <- function(m, n) {
  mn <- m*n
  perm <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(v=0:1, m=mn, repetition=TRUE)
  lapply(1:nrow(perm), function(i) matrix(perm[i, ], nrow=m, ncol=n))
}
```

**Edit:** The benchmark (see below) revealed, a combination of `rcpp` and *@Onyambu*'s `array` solution is very fast:

```
binary3.2 <- function(m, n) {
  mn <- m*n
  perm <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(0:1, mn, TRUE)
  asplit(array(t(perm), c(m, n, 2^(m*n))), 3)
}
```

#### Example using 2 x 2 matrix

```
binary3.2(2, 2)
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    0
# 
# [[2]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    0    1
# 
# [[3]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    0    0
# 
# [[4]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    0    1
# 
# [[5]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    1    0
# 
# [[6]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    0
# [2,]    1    1
# 
# [[7]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    1    0
# 
# [[8]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    0    1
# [2,]    1    1
# 
# [[9]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    0
# 
# [[10]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    0    1
# 
# [[11]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    0    0
# 
# [[12]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    0    1
# 
# [[13]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    1    0
# 
# [[14]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    0
# [2,]    1    1
# 
# [[15]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    0
# 
# [[16]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    1
# [2,]    1    1
```

#### ...and here comes the `microbenchmark`

*Note:* used `m <- 4; n <- 4`

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(b.rcpp(), b.apply.exp(), b.apply.simp(), 
                               b.asplit.array(), b.array(), b.array_tree(),
                               b.rcpp.array(), b.rcpp.arr.aspl(),
                               times=5L, control=list(warmup=5L))

# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval   cld
#          b.rcpp() 388.82227 389.27565 419.43537 408.99157 448.78494 461.3024     5   cd 
#     b.apply.exp() 446.85891 484.10602 502.78558 488.01344 518.98317 575.9664     5    de
#    b.apply.simp() 512.89587 553.52379 588.59234 569.65709 577.65281 729.2322     5     e
#  b.asplit.array() 273.01535 325.13691 320.53399 328.99840 335.36864 340.1507     5  bc  
#         b.array()  27.37996  29.33839  84.25181  39.65228  44.44757 280.4408     5 a    
#    b.array_tree() 322.98764 364.64733 424.07656 391.41701 439.77709 601.5537     5   cd 
#    b.rcpp.array()  51.87000  52.19530  66.88202  53.49471  61.88716 114.9629     5 a    
# b.rcpp.arr.aspl() 261.10201 263.29439 272.21605 278.05505 278.37984 280.2490     5  b
```

#### second benchmark

```
> b.array <- function(m, n) {
+   array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),m*n))),c(m,n,2^(m*n)))
+ }
> 
> b.asplit.array <- function(m, n) {
+   asplit(array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),m*n))),c(m,n,2^(m*n))), 3)
+ }
> b.rcpp.arr <- function(m, n) {
+   perm <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(0:1, m*n, TRUE)
+   array(t(perm), c(m, n, 2^(m*n)))
+ }
> 
> b.rcpp.asp.arr <- function(m, n) {
+   perm <- RcppAlgos::permuteGeneral(0:1, m*n, TRUE)
+   asplit(array(t(perm), c(m, n, 2^(m*n))), 3)
+ }
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(b.array(4, 4), b.asplit.array(4, 4),
+                                b.rcpp.arr(4, 4), b.rcpp.asp.arr(4, 4),
+                                times=100L, control=list(warmup=100L))
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
        b.array(4, 4)  22.69801  27.03368  41.87245  33.35203  37.11160 213.8378   100  a 
 b.asplit.array(4, 4) 231.28149 251.42609 302.35571 295.42282 331.09442 492.8092   100   b
     b.rcpp.arr(4, 4)  32.03322  35.92215  55.64920  50.98276  56.55712 220.2534   100  a 
 b.rcpp.asp.arr(4, 4) 245.92865 272.14143 316.28854 307.01918 335.84227 493.5027   100   b
>
```

Comment: by just typing `asplit` on the screen you will not that it uses the base `for loop`. Could you try with the `array_tree`?. Also for the `rcpp` can you use `array` on it instead of using `lapply`? I believe that combination will be *very fast*

Comment: @Onyambu I've added `array_tree`, it's slower than `asplit` though.

Comment: @Onyambu Did it. `array` vs `rcpp.array` seems a litte ambivalent (due to "small" matrix size probably), but `rcpp.array.asplit` seems to be clearly faster!

Comment: just did the benchmark. `rcpp + array` is faster than the `expand.grid+array`. So you need to check your benchmark again

Comment: @Onyambu Benchmark repeated, actually it seems rcpp is even slower. I've added code that you see what exactly I did. How would you conclude?

Comment: Its amusing to note that rcpp is slower than base R. huh. I have to wrap that around my head

Answer (score 3):

A simpler (and faster) version of the code in [@Bruno's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62458477/8245406). The algorithm is the same, create a list of 16 vectors `0:1`, expand it to all their possible binary strings and coerce each row of this data set into a 4x4 matrix.

```
x <- replicate(4*4, 0:1, simplify = FALSE)
apply(expand.grid(x, KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE), 1, function(x) list(matrix(x, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)))
```

Now the final clean-up.

```
rm(x)
```

## Edit.

Thanks to user **[@Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu)**.

Even [simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458183/how-to-get-all-unique-permutations-of-a-binary-matrix-and-their-ranks-in-r/62458477#comment110460400_62458477),

```
a <- apply(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),16), KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE), 1, function(x) list(matrix(x, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)))
unlist(a, rec = FALSE)
```

And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62458183/how-to-get-all-unique-permutations-of-a-binary-matrix-and-their-ranks-in-r/62458823#comment110461422_62458823), with the result as a 3d array.

```
array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),16))),c(4,4,2^16))
```

Comment: probably you should do `array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),16)),c(4,4,2^16))`

Comment: if you want a list, thenin base R you could use `asplit`: ie `asplit(array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),16)),c(4,4,2^16)),3)`  or replace `asplit` by `purrr::array_tree`

Comment: @Onyambu I would put that as an answer, because its _very_ fast. However seems you have slipped one parentheses: `array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1),16))),c(4,4,2^16))`.

Comment: @Onyambu Second the suggestion to post as an answer. I have updated my answer, with due credits, but you should really post it as your answer.

Comment: Please note microbenchmark I've added to my answer. `asplit` generates considerable overhead but is still fastest.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a 3dimensional array  by doing:

```
 x <- array(t(expand.grid(rep(list(c(0, 1)), 16))), c(4, 4, 2^16))
```

To view the first 2

```
x[,,1:2]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

To have this as a list of matrices:

```
 asplit(x, 3) # in R version >=4.0.0
```

or you could do:

```
 purrr::array_tree(x, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some really slow code

```
# Create options
option <- replicate(16, c(0, 1), simplify = FALSE)
vector_possibilities <- expand.grid(option)



matrixes <- list()

for (i in seq_len(nrow(vector_possibilities)))  {
  matrixes[[i]] <- matrix(vector_possibilities[i,],4)
}


matrixes[1]
```

Comment: did you mean to do `expand.grid(rep(list(c(0,1)),16))`

Comment: Another option - `option <- replicate(16, c(0, 1), simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Oh this is much cleaner I haven't used base in so long...